# mentioned ip to endpoints are not getting configured in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

i am trying to add IPs manually using endpoint object in yaml. however minikube cluster is getting its defaults ips of endpoints instead of mention in the yaml file. why?

yamlfile:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: nginx:1.16
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---        
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
subsets:
    - ports:
      - port: 80
      addresses:
       - ip: 172.17.0.11           ---> configured ip
       - ip: 172.17.0.12           ---> configured ip
       - ip: 172.17.0.13           ---> configured ip
---        
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30464
      port: 90
      targetPort: 80
```

ips in endpoint output:  (see 172.17.0.6, 172.17.0.7 and 172.17.0.8 while i have given 172.17.0.11, 172.17.0.12 and 172.17.0.13 in yaml)

```
/home/ravi/k8s>kubectl get endpoints
NAME            ENDPOINTS                                   AGE
kubernetes      192.168.49.2:8443                           36h
nginx-service   172.17.0.6:80,172.17.0.7:80,172.17.0.8:80   5m59s
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicating your issue and got the configured IP addresses for endpoints.

[image]

[image]

The changes might have occurred due to the namespaces also, Once check it .